How to reduce matrix inversion time?
I am writing a program which requires me to find inverse of a complex 21*21 symmetric matrix several times(approx 35 million times).I initially do this with inv() from scipy.linalg. It works. Now I need to reduce the time it takes.
I searched out online for methods and found that LU decomposition can be used. When I tried to compare time taken by scipy inv and LU method. I found that scipy.inv takes less time even when compared only with the factorization part. Now I have multiple questions-->

What is it which makes scipy uses much less time than numpy and how/where can I find the exact method scipy uses to find inverse of a matrix?
What should I do if I want to reduce computation time(mainly because of matrix inversion) even more?
Any other methods/comments/corrections are invited.

enter image description here
Actually, only the diagonal values of the matrix are changed each time I find an inverse. So, if any approximation method also works if it reduces computational time as compared to time taken by scip.inv. One such example is finding inverse through iterative method. If anyone knows some good approximation method, please suggest.

Is your matrix symmetric or self-adjoint? For the latter, consider using a Cholesky decomposition (either LL* or LDL*, also depending on the positive-definiteness of your matrix). Other than that, do you know anything else about your matrices or the relation between them? And do you really need the inverse, or actually just need to solve Ax=b problems?

Further thing to consider: Do you need double precision or is single precision sufficient in your case? (Using the latter can be up to two times faster, but loses half the accuracy and will over/underflow much sooner).

Also: Please do not upload images of code.

Are any of the inversions you need to do similar? Could you cache some results?

@chtz My matrix is symmetric. Upto my understanding, a self-adjoint matrix is one where A = conj. trans. A. Correct me if i'm wrong. If correct, my matrix is symmetric.
yes, I need to find inverse.
yes, I can use single precision but what do i need to turn it to single precision?

@NickODell Yes, the inversions are a bit similiar. For each time i need to calculate inverse, the diagonal values are changed. No other value is changed.

Thanks. Is the difference between the previous matrix and the current matrix invertable? In other words, is any diagonal element not changed from previous value?

@NickODell Yes, only few diagonal values are changed from the previous value. If I try to approximate, in each inversion 4-5 diagonal elements change. The rest of the matrix remains the same.

If the matrix to be inverted is just a "rank one" update of the previous matrix, you can make use of the Sherman Morrison formula.
"rank one" update means that a matrix of rank 1 is added to the original matrix.

u and v are vectors. The denominator of the fraction is a scalar. Thus, the right-hand term is a matrix divided by a scalar.
This is explained in this article.

Can you explain the meaning behind the division? The bottom is a vector here, right? What is that notation intended to show?

The change is only in the diagonal elements of my matrix. So, I have A but in case of uv^T, I have a 21*21 matrix with only diagonal elements(lets call it B) i.e the rest of elems are 0. I found on the internet that for a diagonal matrix , rank  = no of non-zero elems. Here, all my elems are non-zero. that means that the rank of this is 21. So, will it work here if I take u = B and v = I?

No, as explained here, it is not possible to factor a diagonal matrix into a product of two vectors, unless just one element of the diagonal is non-zero.

@AxelKemper I didn't get it. Suppose my diagonal matrix is B and for factorizing it I use u = B and v = I. v^t = I^t = I and u = B. So, UV^t = BI = B. Basically, it is not factorizing. I am just multiplying I to the matrix B so that the result is B itself and it gets the form as given in the equation. Is this wrong?

You could use a generalization of this formula: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity
